# Is there a way to send a conversion event to Facebook using their API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I'm working on a `SaaS` service. There are certain events that happen on the backend which I'd like to use as conversions for `Facebook Ads`. I figured out there's a way to send a custom event using the `Facebook js-pixel`. I can't use `JS` for the events I'd like to track. Maybe it's possible to use something like a good old-fashioned `cURL`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is the

> **Offline Conversions API**
>
> With Facebook's Offline Conversions API you can send your offline conversion events using an offline event API. You can see how many of your customers viewed or clicked on Facebook ads before converting offline.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/offline-conversions/v2.8

Comment: FYI if you leave off the version number, `v2.8` in this case, it will take you to the latest version of the API, which currently is v2.9 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/offline-conversions