# Is there a way to send an Offline Conversion event to Facebook using restfb?

Tags: java, restfb

The issue asked on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293334/is-there-a-way-to-send-a-conversion-event-to-facebook-using-their-api/42293566#42293566) I have already solved by creating an application that submits an url. But, now I would like to use the [restfb](http://restfb.com/) library to nicely encapsulate the offline conversion.

Since I was unable to find a direct object for use with this library, is there any way to encapsulate an url in a somewhat generic object within restfb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more research, I came across something that seems to answer this.

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: restfb is Graph API. Offline conversions are part of the Marketing API.

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful but there is a tool called Conversion Hero which can help uploading offline conversions via a Webhook https://conversionhero.io